# How can you use the Law of Cosines to show that "u ∙ v = ║u║║v║cosθ "

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, inner-products

How can I do that? I didn't know there was a relationship between those 2?

Comment: The top answer uses the law of cosines.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this is how "angles" are *defined* in non-euclidean settings, such as the "angle" between the sequence $(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\dots)$ and the sequence $(1,0,\frac{1}{3},0,\frac{1}{9},0,\dots)$ in $l_2$.

Comment: Thanks guys, but how can I do the same for ||u x v|| = ||u|| ||v|| sinθ ?

Comment: @user3015986 for one, you can make a new post. In short, though, it comes down to using what we know about dot products.